# udp client packet loss as udp server not waiting

Tags: sockets, networking, udp, packets

Because of my specifications, I have to use UDP packets extensively.
But Do I need to program in such away that I have to listen UDP server always to minimize the packet loss ?
If UDP server is doing some other x operations ,Is there any chance that packet loss will be more ?'
Based on this I have to decrease the operations of UDP server and make that tasks to performed in other threads ..

Answer (score 0):

Your receiving code needs to receive as fast as possible. If a datagram arrives while the socket receive buffer is full it will be discarded.